# "TypeError: t.closest is not a function" on window.getSelection().anchorNode.closest('[data-key]')

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have this html code:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p data-key="0">
        <span data-key="0-0">wsdfsdf</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I put caret into span text and try to get closest parent to caret position using this code:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.closest('[data-key]')
```

But I get error

> "TypeError: t.closest is not a function"

What have I done wrong?

`anchorNode` is pointing to text inside span.

Comment: Text nodes don't have a closest method.

Comment: @JaredSmith, using `parentNode` with `closest` on text node will resolve issue?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to do it should, the parent of the text node should be the p tag.

Comment: @JaredSmith, you was right about "Text nodes don't have a closest method.". This is an unswer to my question.

Comment: *answer, not unswer

Comment: Open the dev tools and enter in the node. You may have a `previousSibling` or `nextSibling` (*maybe*). There are also `childNodes` (again, maybe) and definitely a `parentNode`. There are tons of ways to manipulate the DOM and barring super obnoxious browser bugs the only barrier is your ability to research the tons of long existing JavaScript documentation available. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own functions, like this:

```
function cus_closest(ele,find) {

find = find.toUpperCase();

while(ele.tagName !== find){
if(ele.parentElement !== null )
{ ele = ele.parentElement; }
else return false
}

return ele;

}
```

usage:
for example, if you want to know the closest div(or anything) of your selected text node, you can use this

```
cus_closest(window.getSelection().anchorNode , 'div');
```

you can create another function for data-key custom attribute